# Алгоритм сопоставления

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка, данные

Хочу написать алгоритм оптимального сопоставления (комплектации) значений 2х массивов.
Пример, есть 2 массива данных:
М1 (1 - 60, 2 - 50, 3 - 30, 4 - 40, 5 - 20)
М2 (1 - 70, 2 - 60, 3 - 40, 4 - 10, 5 - 30)
Значения второго массива можно разбивать или суммировать для "покрытия" значений первого. Пример, значение М1 50 можем закрыть значением М2 70 (20 останется в остатке) или М1 50 закрыть значениями М2 40 + 10. При этом нужно учитывать, что оптимально сначала закрывать "цельные" значения М1 - 60 закрыть значением М2 - 60.

Подскажите, в какую сторону "копать".

Comment: Пожалуйста, сформулируйте критерий опимальности.

Comment: @Chorkov Критерий оптимальности - сопоставить как можно больше значений

Comment: Если значения второго массива можно и резать и сшивать, то важна только их сумма. Т.е. выбираем из первого массва элементы, начиная с наименьшего, пока не израсходуем все значения из 2-го. Но это, очевидно, не то решения которого вы ждете. Т.е. критерий, на самом деле, другой.

Comment: Приведу другой пример, М1 (1 - 5, 2 - 5, 3 - 25) М2 (1 - 30). В этом случае оптимально было бы закрыть значением 30 второго массива, значения 25 и 5. Возможна и обратная ситуация. Поэтому алгоритм от меньшего к большему и наоборот не подходит.

Comment: Вы хотите наиболее полно использовать значения из массива M2? Тогда это задача о рюкзаке.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно это она. Только в моем случае будет отсутствовать стоимость.